# how to read file, split record line by line and save them to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

A.O.A

I want to split the following code and save it into database:

```
31201011281853000100000000710003
```

The format of splitting is

```
31

(2010-11-28,18 53) yyyy-mm-dd,hr-min

0001 

0000000071 

0003
```

first I have to upload a file containing these codes and then read each record line by line, split each line in the format I mentioned above, and then save it to database.

Comment: -1 Meals-on-wheels level question.

Answer (score 4):

Use `StreamReader` to read a file line by line and use String.substring method to extract sub-strings.

Answer (score 2):

I +1 AVD's answer, but I thought I'd flesh it out a bit just in case the OP couldn't figure it out on his own.

---

After you've uploaded your file, you'll need to read it using the [streamreader](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader) class.  Using the streamreader, you can read each line into a variable and then perform your split using a [substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring).

StreamReader is in the System.IO namespace.

```
using System.IO;
//------------

string line;
string s1;
string s2;
string s3;
string s4;
string s5;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
   line = reader.ReadLine();  // 31201011281853000100000000710003
   s1 = line.substring(0,2);  // 31
   s2 = line.substring(3,12); // 201011281853
   s3 = line.substring(13,4); // 0001
   s4 = line.substring(14,10);// 0000000071 
   s5 = line.substring(15,4); // 0003

   // Pass s1-s5 to your insert/update statements in DAL.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this: `var records = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt").Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"(\d{2})(\d{12})(\d{4})(\d{10})(\d{4})").Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select((g,i) => i == 1 ? DateTime.ParseExact(g.Value, "yyyyMMddHmm", null).ToString("(yyyy-MM-dd,H mm)") :g.Value ).ToList());`

Hmm...make sure you have a wide monitor then :)